# How to parse and array of arrays with arrays in SwiftyJSON?

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

I have a JSON response like below

```
{
        "geometry" : {
          "type" : "GeometryCollection",
          "geometries" : [
            {
              "type" : "Polygon",
              "coordinates" : [
                [
                  [
                    43.7228393554688,
                    42.065249641381598
                  ],
                  [
                    43.8217163085938,
                    42.084617318779898
                  ],
                  [
                    43.899993896484403,
                    42.100922357518499
                  ],
                  [
                    43.7228393554688,
                    42.065249641381598
                  ]
                ]
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
```

The JSON I posted above is a part of my JSON response. This array gives data in the following format.

```
[[[Array_Polygon1_Coordinates1], [Array_Polygon1_Coordinates2],[Array_Polygon1_Coordinates3]], [[Array_Polygon2_Coordinates1], [Array_Polygon2_Coordinates2], [Array_Polygon2_Coordinates3]]]
```

I am using SwiftyJSON in my project. How can I parse this JSON using SwiftyJSON? 
My code

```
guard let geometries: Array = event["geometry"]["geometries"].array else {
                    throw RMException.invalidFormat
                }
                for geometry: JSON in geometries {
                    if let coordinatesArray: Array = geometry["coordinates"].array {
                        for coordinates: JSON in coordinatesArray {
                            var polygonCoordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []
                            for coordinatePair in coordinates {
                                guard let coordinatePair = coordinatePair.array,
                                    let latitude: Double = coordinatePair.last?.double,
                                    let longitude: Double = coordinatePair.first?.double else {
                                        throw RMException.invalidFormat
                                }

                                polygonCoordinates.append(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude))
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

The error I get is 
[image]

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: @Anbu.karthik added my code to the question

Comment: don't add code as image, past your code and json response

Comment: @PratikPrajapati Sorry. I have updated my question now

Comment: Error indicates that `coordinatePair` is  tuple , try `coordinatePair.1` to get value

Comment: @PratikPrajapati tried it but now `Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'JSON'`

Comment: what are you using for json parsing?

Comment: @PratikPrajapati I am using https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#loop

Comment: @PratikPrajapati Thanks, changed to `coordinatePair.1` and found solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Pratik mentioned in the comment I solved it by

```
if let coordinatesArray: Array = geometry[RMJSONKey.coordinates].array {
   for coordinates: JSON  in coordinatesArray {
       var polygonCoordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []
       for coordinatePair: (String, JSON) in coordinates {
           let coordinateSet: JSON = coordinatePair.1
           guard let latitude: Double = coordinateSet.arrayValue.last?.double,
           let longitude: Double = coordinateSet.arrayValue.first?.double else {
                throw RMException.invalidFormat
           }
          polygonCoordinates.append(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude))
       }
   }
}
```